How do I customize my Azure AD B2C sign-in user flow email MFA verification template?
I have built a web app and hosted it using Azure App Service and I am using Azure AD B2C for its authentication method for which I have MFA enabled through email. Is there a way to modify the banner and logo at the email verification template that is currently set to default by Azure AD B2C? I have included an image below where I wish to change the top blue color and the CONTOSO logo at the bottom.

I have taken this snapshot from this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/faq?tabs=app-reg-ga
For which they mentioned the following:
You can use the company branding feature to customize the content of verification emails. Specifically, these two elements of the email can be customized:

Banner logo: Shown at the bottom-right.

Background color: Shown at the top.


The email signature contains the Azure AD B2C tenant's name that you provided when you first created the Azure AD B2C tenant. You can change the name using these instructions:

Sign in to the Azure portal as the Global Administrator.

Open the Microsoft Entra ID blade.

Select the Properties tab.

Change the Name field.

Select Save at the top of the page.


But I seem to not be able to find the following settings in the Azure AD B2C company branding, I could only find the options to customize the sign-in page look by setting the sign-in page background image, banner logo, sign-in page text, sign-in page background color, and square logo image.
I have tried looking into my Azure AD B2C company branding tab and my Microsoft Entra ID company branding tab, but I am unable to find the following customization options.

You need to navigate to the Microsoft Entra ID related to your Azure B2C tenant.
Switch to the B2C tenant directory (in this case Custom B2C Tenant Name) and click View on the Manage Microsoft Entra ID blade.

On the next page you'll find the Name input field (menu Overview -> tab Properties) and Company branding - on the bottom left (menu Manage -> Company branding -> tab/blade Default sign-in). The first option is shown in the second image.

The latter option is presented in the image below. Page background color (in the 'Basic' tab) is also responsible for the background color of the email header. Banner logo in the 'Sign-in form' tab will add the logo to the email footer.

Once you have updated and saved B2C tenant name and company branding, you'll see the changes in your Verification and MFA emails.
Please note that updates may appear with some delay for an hour (mostly related to the B2C tenant name and to banner/background color if you update them frequently).

@I K, Thanks for the response, but I am unable to see the fields for banner background color option and the footer logo in the company branding section. I am only able to see "Basic", "Sign-in form", and "Preview" tabs. I only have the following options: Banner logo, Square logo (light theme), Square logo (dark theme), Username hint text, and Sign-in page text under the "Sign-in form" tab. And under the "Basics" tab I can only see Background image and Page background color option.

@JasonSusanto I added some updates: all you need is Page background color in the Basic tab and Banner logo in the Sign-in form tab

thanks for the reply and update. Let me give it a try and Ill keep you posted.
